# Send F6 to linux in java

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons

I use apache commons-net.jar to connect to a linux box. After login, I want to send an F6 , like I press key F6 in netterm.

```
String s = "\033ou";     
try {  
         out.write(s.getBytes());  
         out.flush();  
         //System.out.println(s);  
     } catch (Exception e) {  }
```

Linux does not send  any response , not say correct. What's the problem?

Comment: Here is the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181877/java-telnet-apache-commons-how-to-send-functions-keys

Comment: *send a F6 key* can mean different things. Some emulators can send the peer a sequence of characters. But `"\033ou"` looks weird, according to the *standard* DEC VT220, F6 normally sends `CSI 1 7 ~`, said differently `"\033[17~"`. Could you give some more context?

Comment: oh, I should say more. I set term type to VT100 according to the user guide of the application,  I know F6 sends  '\033ou' by way of sniffer.

Answer (score 0):

The reference `"\033ou"` is a string representation involving many characters, while you might be targeting to send a single unicode character. Once you are sure about the unicode character to be sent, you might do `out.write(new char [] {'\u0330'})` or `out.write((int)'\u0330')` or `out.write(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_F6)`